# How to understand the residue concerning the Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

Why does the term of residue have no primitive in the deleted neighborhood of Z，but other terms have？And why the integration of the principal part equals to the residue？

Comment: Note $\frac{z^{n+1}}{n+1}$ is an antiderivative for $n \neq -1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrating an integer power of $z$ gives you another power of $z$ (up to constant) except precisely when $n = -1$. This remarkable fact is the foundation of the residue theory. In particular, other than at $n = -1$, an antiderivative of $z^n$ is a multiple of $z^{n+1}$.

For $n = -1$, we'd expect some sort of logarithm, just as how in one real variable, an antiderivative of $1/x$ is $\log{x}$ for $x > 0$. However, this logarithm cannot be analytic in a neighborhood of the origin (and requires a branch cut to be defined precisely; you will likely learn about this soon in your analysis course). Informally, this logarithm behavior produces the residue, since if $z = re^{i\theta}$ then a hypothetical logarithm of $z$ would be $\log{r} + i\theta$; however $\theta$ is not well-defined, and furthermore $\theta$ is not continuous in $z$ and increments by $2\pi$ as you go around the origin, which what you do when you integrate a contour about the origin.

Answer (score 0):

If $1/(z-z_0)$ had a primitive, it's integral would be independent of path, and then the integral around any  loop would be zero.  This is essentially the fundamental theorem of calculus.

The primitive for $1/(z-z_0)$ would have to be $\log(z-z_0)$, which can't be defined continuously on the whole loop.

For the same reason, the integral of every term except $a_{-1}/(z-z_0)$ vanishes.  They all have primitives (power rule).

The residue theorem ensures, meanwhile, that that terms integral is the residue.  You can also do it by direct calculation.